# Node/Grunt - Autoprefixer - How to add configuration to my Gruntfile.js & how to check supported browsers?

Tags: javascript, css, node.js, gruntjs, vendor-prefix

I want to start using the CSS post-processor called autoprefixer (https://github.com/ai/autoprefixer).

After a bit of juggling things around I actually got this working which is quite amazing to me since I am an absolute node, grunt and terminal beginner.
In the [autoprefixer documentation](https://github.com/ai/autoprefixer#browsers) it says one can configure which browsers to support, as explanation this line of code is given:

```
autoprefixer("last 1 version", "> 1%", "ie 8", "ie 7").compile(css);
```

But where do I put this code? I tried to paste it into the bottom my Gruntfile without success. The file looks like this:

```
module.exports = function (grunt) {
    grunt.initConfig({
        autoprefixer: {
            dist: {
                files: {
                    'build/style.css': 'style.css'
                }
            }
        },
        watch: {
            styles: {
                files: ['style.css'],
                tasks: ['autoprefixer']
            }
        }
    });
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-autoprefixer');
    grunt.loadNpmTasks('grunt-contrib-watch');
};
```

I also tried to add it like this:

```
autoprefixer: {
    options: {
      browsers: ["last 10 version", "> 1%", "ie 8", "ie 7"]
    },
    dist: {
        files: {
            'build/style.css': 'style.css'
        }
 },
```

This has definitely an influence on the CSS output, but I am not sure if it is correct?

Also, when I type `autoprefixer -i` into the command line to check for my config, the output is `-bash: autoprefixer: command not found`. The same goes for `grunt-autoprefixer -i`. How can I fix this? I would love to see the versions I support.
Another variation is to do it like this:

```
inspect = autoprefixer("last 1 version").inspect();
console.log(inspect);
```

But again, where to put this code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to global install autoprefixer to has `autoprefixer` command:

```
sudo npm install -g autoprefixer
autoprefixer -i
```

Comment: Wow, Andrey Sitnik himself answers my question, thank you! I am using Autoprefixer now daily on various projects and have also introduced it to my team and everyone loves it, great work!

Answer (score 2):

Now you can use Autoprefixer binary from the project folder without globally installed Autoprefixer (don't forget to update grunt-autoprefixer to v0.4.1).

[Here](https://github.com/nDmitry/grunt-autoprefixer#options) you can find `browsers` option description. Options can be target- or task-specific, and target-specific options can override task-specific.