# Some inline style is missing in IE due to Vue

Tags: css, vue.js

I have this code:

```
<div style="display: -ms-grid; -ms-grid-columns: 2fr 1fr 2fr 2fr;">
    foo
</div>
```

When I inspect it in IE, I can only see `display: -ms-grid`.

Where is `-ms-grid-columns: 2fr 1fr 2fr 2fr;` Was it never added to the DOM or was it removed again? What can I do to get/keep it?

Comment: It works for me in both IE11 and Edge. Try checking it on https://jsfiddle.net/kev9fmps/ if it shows up there, then the error's probably somewhere else (e.g. do you use webpack or CSS preprocessors or something?)

Comment: I can't open jsfiddle in IE. "IE is not supported.". Yes we use Grunt to compile our .less.

Comment: Should work in IE11, but only in readmode, that should be enough (it should show an alert that says "Launch fiddle in read-only mode", then click "Ok")

Comment: You're right, I can also now see it in IE jsfiddle. So maybe it's my Grunt that's removing it? I don't know how that would be possible, but now it doesn't seem to be the browser fault right :/

Comment: Maybe try adding the standard declaration too? So: `grid-template-columns: 2fr 1fr 2fr 2fr;`, maybe it gets removed if only the prefixed attribute is present (though I kinda doubt it. But I don't know any other solution)

Comment: I've tryed it. It seems like everything that starts with "-ms-" is never added or removed.

Comment: Then I'd say it's because of the Grunt config. Do you use postcss/autoprefixer? If yes, then check here: https://github.com/postcss/autoprefixer#browsers and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19281182/node-grunt-autoprefixer-how-to-add-configuration-to-my-gruntfile-js-how-to on how to define which browsers you want to support. Probably some `-ms-` prefixes are getting removed because they're deprecated for the browsers you defined (or for the Grunt-default)

Comment: Now im pretty sure its our Vue thats doing it.

Comment: If you are sure about the cause of the issue than I suggest you to post your solution or a work around for this issue as an answer for this question and  try to mark your own answer as an accepted answer for this question after 48 hrs, when it is available to mark. It can help other community members in future in similar kind of issues. Thanks for your understanding.

Comment: I don't know why Vue is doing this. It must have some sort of build it css vendor stuff running. But it's 100% a Vue thing.